# Get EditText in a listview outside of Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with an EditText in each row.
Each EditText has his validation, so, when I click the MenuItem "Finish", I want to make the validation of each EditText and show errors if there were any.

I know how to access my EditText inside my adapter, but inside my adapter, I can't access MenuItem.
Outside my adapter, I can access my MenuItem OnClick, but I can't get my edittext values anymore...

Any solution???

Comment: You could set a field in your adapter (like `needValidation`) to `true` when the user click on the "Finish" menu. And then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter. So you will have access to your views again. Once the validation is done, set `needValidation` to `false` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using : [ListView item set error Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374921/listview-item-set-error-android)

The solution was to include an ArrayList of errors in the adapter.

Tx for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through your listView and do something like:

```
View v = myList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(nameOfTheView);
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293740/iterate-through-listview-and-get-edittext-field-values).

Comment: By using `null` for the `convertView` and `parent` parameters of the `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method, you loose the recycling strategy and may end up with the wrong `LayoutParam` for the current view.

Comment: I can access the values with that, but I can't display errors with setErrors. Do you know how to modify the view inside the adapter?

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do is setup a class to hold variables:

```
public class MyVarHolder {
    public EditText myText;
}
```

Then you use it into your getView method:

```
mHolder.myText = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
convertView.setTag(mHolder);
```

Last step is get the holder into the onClickListener of your list:

```
onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    MyVarHolder tag = (MyVarHolder)view.getTag();

   String editText = tag.myText.getText().toString();

   ...Do whatever you want...

}
```

Comment: This is INSIDE my Adapter, I need to access it OUTSIDE, in the activity

Comment: `onItemClickListener` will be outside into your `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: I need to validate throught the menuItem, not the onItemClickListener, otherwise, I could do it in the adapter

Comment: What do you mean for `MenuItem`?

Comment: A button in the ActionBar

Comment: Sorry but you should have specify that. it is not clare from your answer. please give more informations